# Multi-stage docker build is failing because it can't see R from the first build

Tags: r, docker, bioconductor

**Problem**

I'm trying to create a multi-image Dockerfile that first pulls the bioconductor image, invokes a setup R script, and then pulls an ubuntu image to install python-related packages. Even though I've saved R to path from the first-stage build, it appears this is not retained after the second-stage build, because when I invoke the entrypoint script `run_deseq2.py`, it says: `/bin/sh: 1: Rscript: not found`. How can I properly combine these two stages in the same dockerfile so that they can still "see" each other?

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM bioconductor/release_base2

ADD src/setup.R /
RUN Rscript /setup.R

ENV PATH=/usr/local/bin/:$PATH

FROM ubuntu:19.04 

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive  

WORKDIR / 

RUN apt-get update && \ 
    apt-get install -y \ 
        python-dev \ 
        python-pip \ 
        wget 

RUN pip install awscli boto3

COPY src/run_deseq2.py /
COPY src/s3_utils.py /
COPY src/job_utils.py /
COPY src/deseq2.R /
COPY src/ModelLoxTag.R /

ENV R_THREADS=30 

# Run docker, starting with run script
ENTRYPOINT ["python", "/run_deseq2.py"]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
FROM bioconductor/release_base2 AS buidler
ADD src/setup.R /
RUN Rscript /setup.R
ENV PATH=/usr/local/bin/:$PATH

FROM ubuntu:19.04 
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive  
WORKDIR / 
RUN apt-get update && \ 
    apt-get install -y \ 
        python-dev \ 
        python-pip \ 
        wget 
RUN pip install awscli boto3
COPY --from=builder src/run_deseq2.py /   #If you want to copy something from stage-1 use from 
COPY src/s3_utils.py /
COPY src/job_utils.py /
COPY src/deseq2.R /
COPY src/ModelLoxTag.R /
ENV R_THREADS=30 
# Run docker, starting with run script
ENTRYPOINT ["python", "/run_deseq2.py"]
```

i don't know much R so can't help with whole docker image but you can tag stage using `AS` and in another stage you can copy paste files.

more details you can also check officeial dock : https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/